# export over import via asterisk

Tags: reactjs, native

I'm looking for a way to export over import for none default exports. I know the way for default exports:

```
export ( default as DefaultExport ) from './default_export';
```

But do anybody know the right way of following wrong way:

```
export ( * as WhatEver ) from './whatever';
```

Comment: why do you want to export many things from a file using a single name

Comment: Some people like to use so called bucket files to group their exports to avoid circular dependencies and a clear import path for example `import { formatDate } from '../utils';` replacing `import { formatDate } from '../utils/dateFormatters':`.

Comment: In fact, it's about to group a collection of individual functions.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of making life easier on your linter it's safer to do `export { x1, x2, ... }` but if you really want an all you can do `export * from 'file1'`. The latter will make all your `export x1; export x2;` be available for normal destructured importing.

The latter will also in most cases imply your linter warning you for an unfound export since you're exporting `*` and he can't find the explicit name of what you're importing from there.

Comment: I was just wondering why I can group with an asterisk imports but not immediately pass this group as an export. It would just be a practical thing.

Comment: But you can i just said so in my answer.